# How to recieve a message sent from content script to popup.js/html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I can't figure out how to send some data from my content script to `popup.html`. It's an `xpath` of clicked element. I'm very new to **Chrome Extensions** so maybe it's obvious.

I've read articles about message passing but I have a mess there.

I figured out how to send a message from `xpathget.js` but I don't know how to recieve it and show it on `popup.html` since it closes after I click on some element.

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Product",
  "description": "This is a plugin collaborating with product.com",
  "version": "1.0",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "spy-icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_title": "Click here!"
  },
  "icons":{
    "64":"spy-icon.png"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["authentication.js"]
  },
    "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["xpathget.js"]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "https://ajax.googleapis.com/",
    "cookies",
    "<all_urls>"
  ],
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://ajax.googleapis.com; object-src 'self'"
}
```

**popup.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('body').height(280);
    $('html').height(280);
    MESSAGE_GET_HANDLER(){
        ALTER_THE_HTML; 
    }
});
```

I suppose that I have to send `xpath` string to `popup.js` which then alters the `popup.html` html and it's done.

**xpathget.js**

```
document.onclick= function(event) {
    if (event===undefined) event= window.event;                     // IE hack
    var target= 'target' in event? event.target : event.srcElement; // another IE hack

    var root= document.compatMode==='CSS1Compat'? document.documentElement : document.body;
    var mxy= [event.clientX+root.scrollLeft, event.clientY+root.scrollTop];

    var path= getPathTo(target);
    var txy= getPageXY(target);
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({xpath: path}, function () {
         alert('sent');
    }); <== I HAVE TO SEND THIS PATH TO PLUGIN
}

function getPathTo(element) {
    if (element.id!=='')
        return 'id("'+element.id+'")';
    if (element===document.body)
        return element.tagName;

    var ix= 0;
    var siblings= element.parentNode.childNodes;
    for (var i= 0; i<siblings.length; i++) {
        var sibling= siblings[i];
        if (sibling===element)
            return getPathTo(element.parentNode)+'/'+element.tagName+'['+(ix+1)+']';
        if (sibling.nodeType===1 && sibling.tagName===element.tagName)
            ix++;
    }
}

function getPageXY(element) {
    var x= 0, y= 0;
    while (element) {
        x+= element.offsetLeft;
        y+= element.offsetTop;
        element= element.offsetParent;
    }
    return [x, y];
}
```

Comment: Can you better explain what is actually happening in your extension? Is clicking something on the page supposed to open the popup and pass the message? Not exactly clear on the flow here.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to keep the toolbar popup open once you click on a webpage or anywhere outside the popup. Once it's closed its environment/context/objects and event listeners don't exist anymore.
The toolbar popup can't be re-opened programmatically as well.

Continue the interaction in a DOM dialog/div added to the webpage like [uBlock's element picker does.](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/wiki/Element-picker) or open a new window with `'popup'` type via [chrome.windows.create](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#method-create).